# Too many redirects with Virtual Host and htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multiple-domains

### The issue im getting is too many redirects.

I have a WAMP server that hosts a few sites, but I have a particular site with about 5 domains. I want them all to point to the correct website folder and all to be redirected to  a single domain for SEO purposes. 
Here is what it looks like in the virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost 50.62.82.101>
ServerAdmin info@hovaness.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/example"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.net www.example.com www.examples.net www.examples.com examples.com examples.net
ErrorLog "logs/example.com.log"
```

The htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sellingwarriors.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

Am I only supposed to have one or the other?
I have also tried in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?).example(s?).(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check for the hostname that you are redirecting to, otherwise it will continue to redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```